# Entry in main table of contents but not in sub ToC of individual parts

Tags: table-of-contents, parts

I'm writing a document with multiple parts. I would like to have a main ToC for the whole document at the beginning, but also a (more detailed) ToC for each of the individual Parts. I already achieved this using the minitoc package. For each Part, I would now like to add a ToC line in the **main** ToC, pointing to the individual **sub** ToC's of that Part. That is, the main ToC should look something like:

[image]

I managed to produce this with the following minimal working example, using the command `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Detailed table of contents for Part I}`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}
\doparttoc\tableofcontents

\part{First Part}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Detailed table of contents for Part I}
\mtcsettitle{parttoc}{Sub-ToC for Part 1}
\parttoc

\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}

\part{Second Part}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Detailed table of contents for Part II}
\mtcsettitle{parttoc}{Sub-ToC for Part 2}
\parttoc

\chapter{Third Chapter}
\chapter{Fourth Chapter}

\end{document}
```

However, now the **sub** ToC for each Part *also* has this line added to its own ToC, i.e. it looks like:

[image]

How can I remove the line from the **sub** ToC while keeping the line in the **main** ToC?